# Python does not print unique word's multiple positions from string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, position

The question is to create a function that reads a string and print a dictionary listing the positions for each UNIQUE word. The key is the word and the value is a list of its positions in the string.

Here would be an example string:

`One fish two fish red fish blue fish`

The correct output would be:

`{'two': [2], 'one': [0], 'red': [4], 'fish': [1, 3, 5, 7], 'blue': [6]}`

Here is my output:

`{'blue': [6], 'two': [2], 'red': [4], 'fish': [1], 'One': [0]}`

As you notice, the word 'fish' is repeated multiple times in this string. It is not just in position 1. What code do I need to add to print out the multiple positions of any word?

Here is my code:

```
def wordPositions(s):
    d = {}

    words = s.split()
    for word in words:
        lst = []
        lst.append(words.index(word))
        d[word] = lst
    return d
print(wordPositions('One fish two fish red fish blue fish'))
```

Comment: ...I don't think unique means what you think it means

Comment: If a word like "fish" is repeated multiple times in your string, it is not unique. "one", "two", "red" and "blue" are the unique words in that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
s = 'One fish two fish red fish blue fish'
res = {}

for i, v in enumerate(s.split(' ')):
    if v in res:
        res[v].append(i)
    else:
        res[v] = [i]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
{'blue': [6], 'fish': [1, 3, 5, 7], 'two': [2], 'red': [4], 'One': [0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = 'One fish two fish red fish blue fish'
d = defaultdict(list)
for i, word in enumerate(s.split()):
    d[word.lower()].append(i)
```

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). [`d.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) is then

```
dict_items([('one', [0]), ('blue', [6]), ('two', [2]), ('red', [4]), ('fish', [1, 3, 5, 7])])
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another answer ...

```
>>> words='One fish two fish red fish blue fish'.split()
>>> counts={}
>>> for word in set(words):
...     counts[word]=[_ for _ in range(len(words)) if words[_]==word]
...     
>>> counts
{'blue': [6], 'two': [2], 'fish': [1, 3, 5, 7], 'red': [4], 'One': [0]}
```